# NavBar Customization

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight, devexpress, navbar

I have been working on this navbar for hours. What I want to do is make the background blue and the foreground white. Can some one tell me how to customize the code below in order to achieve this.
I am using Visual Studios Silverlight. This control is coming from DevExpress. I have tried doing the background Blue several times and it does not work. Also, Foreground is not an option when trying to change the NavBar Header.

```
<dxn:NavBarControl x:Name="navBar1" Margin="10">
                <dxn:NavBarControl.View>
                    <dxn:SideBarView/>
                </dxn:NavBarControl.View>
                <dxn:NavBarGroup Header="Financial Indicators">
                    <dxn:NavBarItem >
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                <localmetric:EBIT x:Name="ebit" Width="410" Margin="10" Foreground="#FF0042FF"/>
                                <localmetric:ROIC x:Name="roic" Width="410" Margin="10" Foreground="#FF0042FF"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <localmetric:FinancialRatios x:Name="financialratio" Width="800" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FF0042FF"/>
                            <localmetric:CashFlow x:Name="cashflow" Width="500" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FF0042FF"/>

                        </StackPanel>
                    </dxn:NavBarItem>

                </dxn:NavBarGroup>
                <dxn:NavBarGroup Header="Efficiency">
                    <dxn:NavBarItem >
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <localmetric:Efficiency1 x:Name="efficiency1" Width="700" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FF0042FF"/>
                            <localmetric:Efficiency2 x:Name="efficiency2" Width="700" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FF0042FF"/>
                            <localmetric:Efficiency3 x:Name="efficiency3" Width="700" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FF0042FF"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </dxn:NavBarItem>
                </dxn:NavBarGroup>
```

Comment: Whose is that? DevExpress? They don't just have those properties template bound so you could just literally say Background="Blue" Foreground="White"?

Comment: Sorry, Yes it is DevExpress. I forgot about that. I have tried doing the background Blue several times and it does not work. Also, Foreground is not an option when trying to change the NavBar Header

Comment: Did you go through their [docs on styling](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#Silverlight/CustomDocument5083), it looks like you just need to specify your own VisualStyle template.

Comment: Yes, I looked through it before asking the question. All they give is public Brush Foreground { get; set; } Which I am not sure what to do with.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample provided by Devexpress team to customize the styles of NavBar. http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q349640 and http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q499695

Comment: Is there any examples that are in Silverlight form. These are all in WPF and I can not figure out how to get it to work.